# Enabling Popovers using Twitter Bootstrap's "bootstrap-popover.js" in Rails 3.2

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Newbie to Ruby on Rails and Twitter Bootstrap :P

Trying to add a popover to an image where, when you scroll over it,  a popout appears with a larger version of the image.

The image:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
  <div class="span1">
    <ul>
     <li>
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/125x100" alt=""></a>
     </li>
  </div>
    </ul>
```

I'm trying to use Twitter Bootstrap's "Popovers" by adding "bootstrap-popover.js" and 'bootstrap-tooltip.js' (which it extends) to the appropriate folders in my asset directory (using Rails 3.2).

If I wanted to activate it so the popout works when I scroll over the image, how would I do this?

I'm really just not sure how to call a specific element for the popover to work on.

[image: What I'm trying to make happen :)]

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this javascript statement in after wherever you link your javascript files. This will activate the popover for all 'a' elements (links in your page).

```
$('a').popover(placement:'top');
```

Try this code to test it out. setting the rel, title, and data-content attributes in the link tag will activate the popever on that element.

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
  <div class="span1">
    <ul>
     <li>
      <a href="#" rel="popover" title="A Title" data-content="<img src='http://placehold.it/125x100'/>">Hover over me for image.</a>
     </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much chapman84! I tested it for a bit and had to actually put <li><a href="#" rel="popover" title="A Title" data-content= <img src='http://placehold.it/125x100'/> <img src='http://placehold.it/125x100'/></a>, the other code just displayed "hover over for image"

Comment: Cool. Glad it got you in the right direction. I have used the popovers on my table header elements. I don't have images but I have unordered lists so I figured the image would work as well.

Comment: Have you ever specified the popover to look like the above image? I'm trying to get that effect but have it popover above it instead of to the right of it...:p

Comment: On that line of javascript you added change the placement:'top' to placement:'right'. You can do top, right, left, and bottom.

Comment: Thanks again Chapman, it doesn't seem to work (stays the same type of popover and int he same place no matter what I specify) so I've posted a more descriptive question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658151/styling-popovers-in-twitter-bootstraps-bootstrap-popover-js-in-rails-3-2

Comment: @GirlCanCode2 - You've been posting a lot of duplicate questions. That's not good. Instead of posting duplicates, please just edit your question to be more descriptive. (If you haven't yet, please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), especially [this section](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) )