# Styling "popovers" in Twitter Bootstrap's “bootstrap-popover.js” in Rails 3.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Using Rails 3.2 and Twitter Bootstrap “bootstrap-popover.js" and "bootstrap-tooltip.js" [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popover)

This is what I'd like to happen :

[image: P]

for when I hover over:

```
 <li>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/125x100" alt=""></a>
 </li>
```

In both “bootstrap-popover.js" and "bootstrap-tooltip.js" I have **$('a').popover(placement:'top');**.

What other options could I possibly specify in order to have the popout appear like it is in the picture above, with options "A title" and "And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging right?"

Here's a pic of what I currently get:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example of what it sounds like you want:
http://jsfiddle.net/chapmanc/DuKCg/4/

Also you only need to put the line of javascript in one place. I usually create a new .js file with all my custom functions and include that in my page the same way you are including the popover and tooltip scripts.

For example the bottom of your file might look like:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-tooltip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-popover.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/customFunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

With customFunctions.js having the:

```
$('a').popover({placement:'right'});
```

Comment: HI Chapman, I really appreciate all your help. TY. I've done everything you've said but am still getting (See updated pic above) even when I put $('a').popover({placement:'right'}); in bootstrap-popover.js. I think it has something to do with the fact that popover "extends" tooltip, so I'm just gonna keep playing around with things. Thank you for all your effort!